# Solarwinds SWQL to Query Data for Routers and Switches

Tags: networking, router, solarwindslem

Does anybody know where to find Sample Solarwinds SWQLs to get Health Data for Routers and Switches? If anybody can post any samples, would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

It's plausible that the easiest way to retrieve router/switch health data may be by configuring OID/MIB imports using the Universal Device Poller (UnDP) tool available on your primary poller.

Simple google searches can get you to recent unified MIB listings, which you can collect from the target devices and display in node-related pages of your discretion and design.

It's admittedly tedious, but once they're in they're good until you replace the hardware, so long as you're willing to commit to SNMP polling of the device.  Further the tool allows you to perform trial-and-error testing before committing the MIB import you're working on.  Note for reference I'm referring to NPM11.5/12.  Earlier versions should have this tool up to a point, but no promises.

Comment: alternately, if the data is already coming in from the Hardware Health Agent, you can create a draft alert using that data, then use the "show SWQL" option in the alert trigger step to see what tables it's calling and how.

Comment: To top that off, you can connect to the thin client's SWIS query tool, https://SERVER/Orion/admin/swis.aspx and test your Select statements there once you start tailoring the sample query to meet your needs.